# What is the difference in the rituals per varna post upanayanam?

Tags: rituals, upanayanam

I know that the upanayanam is performed by the first 3 varna and only they are allowed to wear the thread. Even the threads are of different material cotton, hemp and wool. Presumably the rituals that are performed also differ per varna as well as the food and drink that may be consumed (for example I know that Kshatriya and Shudra varna are allowed meat) but the other two are not in general.

So what is the difference in the rituals for dvija after initiation?